# More smoke and smoke colour

Tags: smoke-simulation

The standard answer for smoke colour in Blender >2.8 is to write "color" in the "Color Attribute" field in the principled volume node. But this seems to have no effect.

Also there is much too little smoke I don't see the emission amount to have any effect?

And is it possible to have the smoke trace a litte bit more confined?

Attached please find the .blend.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include more detail and description as to how your scene is set up and the results you are seeing, instead of relying on someone downloading your .blend. This makes the question more accessible and more applicable to other people's situation. Include screenshots of your setup and results and maybe provide links to the 'standard answer' you refer to and how that doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: I've tried to give you an answer on the possibilities of coloring the smoke. The _Surface Emission_ tells Blender how far away from the surface smoke will appear, it's not making more or less. Hovering your mouse over the value will give you the information. You might consider using the _Volume Emission_ as well. And the _Density_ setting in _Principled Volume_ shader of your domain is just 5, maybe try 20 or even 50 to get more visible smoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file has a fluid object where *Smoke Color* is set to black, and in your domain material, the *Color* in the *Principled Volume* node is also set to black. If you want colored smoke, you have to set colors to the volume at some point or another.

Sorry for a very long answer now but I want to give you examples on how to use color on the smoke. It works like this - I'm using two *Flow Objects* in a single domain with only one domain material:

1. In the settings of the *Flow Object* you can specify a *Smoke Color*. This is first of all shown in the *Solid View* so you can distinguish them in the *3D Viewport*.

[image: smoke color 1]

2. In *Rendered View* however, if your domain material is set to the default grey color without any *Color Attribute* set, it shows the default grey.

[image: smoke color 2]

3. If you enter the *Color Attribute* "color", the smoke gets colored by the *Flow Object* settings, but they are darker than the original colors because they are combined with the grey color set in the *Principled Volume* node.

[image: smoke color 3]

4. You can even give them a different tint by keeping the attribute and changing the node's color setting. I don't understand exactly how the colors are mixed, I guess it has something to do with volume absorption.

[image: smoke color 4]

5. A different way to color the smoke is to use the *Volume Info* node. If you plug it into the *Color* socket of the *Principled Volume* shader without using the *Color Attribute*, it colors the smoke according to the settings of the *Flow Objects*.

[image: smoke color 5]

6. This is just the same as if you were using the *Color Attribute* and combining it with full white in the node's *Color* setting.

[image: smoke color 6]

7. Using both the *Volume Info* node and the *Color Atrribute* will combine each color with itself instead of a single tint for both, meaning it will make the colors more intense (and maybe a little darker, too).

[image: smoke color 7]

Comment: Thats one huge effort of an answer! I award you my personal hero badge. I've never awarded a bounty before. I guess accepting = giving the bounty? If not please contact! The bounty is very well earned! Thank you!

Comment: I think you could somehow give the bounty actively to an answer, but when it expires the accepted will get it somehow if you don't do it. But the word _bounty_ at the top is linked to an article, I think there it is explained. I just offered a bounty for the first time myself, but I had to find the answer myself (and I cannot earn my own bounty).

Comment: Ah ok, great to know.  I looked it up and you can award the bounty by clicking the icon showing the +50. Did so right now :-)